The passive voice of a sentence with different tenses
I have come across a sentence in a passive voice exercise. Unfortunately, I couldn't find the answer key as it was published separately. To make it much challenging to change into the passive, the sentence shows different tenses which give rise to the discrepancy between the manifest structure and the implied meaning.
The sentence to change into the passive voice goes:

It's high time somebody told him the truth.

Any suggestions with some explanation, please?

This a case of passivisation of the subordinate clause, not the matrix clause. The logical passive version is: "It’s high time [he was told the truth by somebody]". Note that although "was" is a past tense form. it does not relate to past time. It's called a modal preterite.

I do agree with you, still the main clause dominates the entire meaning as it refers to some necessary future action. I am not sure but we should change the past verb in the dependent clause into something similar to that of 'it's high time' expression.

@FerasMuhaidat Why would you "change the past verb"? In "It is high time that" you're using a simple present indicative. That verb form will not work in the clause it governs. It's just like "I wish that" in this regard. In any case, you have to leave that main clause alone.

@tchrist the present reference of "high time" is for the moment of speaking which is not the same temporal frame of reference of the "telling", or is it?

@FerasMuhaidat You're right that there is a difference between “It is high time that...” versus “It was high time that...”. But you aren’t going to change the main clause at all; that would not make any sense given how there’s no transitive verb whose object complement you could promote into the subject of an inflected be + past participle form of that transitive verb — because you’ve already started with be being used in a copula, and that cannot be passivized.

@tchrist all right. Suppose that we could change this complex sentence into a simple, passive one without changing the meaning, what would  that sentence be? Actually, I already have some possible suggestions that I'm not sure about, like "he should/ought to/had better/must be told the truth." I think that these modals in the suggested answer still miss the shade of annoyance expressed in "it's high time". What do you think of it?

@FerasMuhaidat For comparable simple sentences instead of complex ones, with minimal meaning change, I would use the strongest deontic modal  of obligation available (ᴍᴜsᴛ) and then add something like finally/belatedly/at last/at long last to incorporate the ‘high time’ notion that this truth-telling is overdue. So perhaps “Someone must finally tell him the truth” paired with “He must finally be told the truth” will work for your non-complex versions, although I cannot recommend “The truth must finally be told to him” for most (if perhaps not quite ᴀʟʟ conceivable) circumstances.

You just flip somebody told him into he were told by somebody. So the original:

It’s high time (that) somebody told him the truth.

becomes this if promoting the indirect object to subject:

It’s high time (that) he were told the truth by somebody.

or this if promoting the direct object to subject:

It’s high time (that) the truth were told to him by somebody.

It would be more common to promote the indirect object as in (2) than the direct object as in (3).
In formal writing, it would be were not was in the passive version. That’s because the verb following it’s (high) time (that) has historically been in what was once called the past subjunctive in earlier forms of English, and which is retained morphologically only with be. Casual conversational language and writing in a less-than-formal register would more often use was, though, especially in the UK rather than the US.
Occasionally these it’s time constructions take for–to infinitives instead of that clauses:

It’s high time for somebody to tell him the truth.

would become

It’s high time for him to be told the truth by somebody.

or, at least in theory, but it sounds pretty bad:

It’s high time for the truth to be told to him by somebody.


In comments to the original question, the asker wondered what an equivalent simple sentence might be so that we don’t have two different clauses to consider. I had this to offer:

For comparable simple sentences instead of complex ones, with minimal meaning change, I would use the strongest deontic modal  of obligation available (ᴍᴜsᴛ) and then add something like finally/belatedly/at last/at long last to incorporate the ‘high time’ notion that this truth-telling is overdue. So perhaps “Someone must finally tell him the truth” paired with “He must finally be told the truth” will work for your non-complex versions, although I cannot recommend “The truth must finally be told to him” for most (if perhaps not quite ᴀʟʟ conceivable) circumstances.


Thanks for the rich information, but don't you think that the indirect object hasn't been told the truth yet? According to Bollinger's principle, your sentence with the infinitive still refers to a future action.

@FerasMuhaidat What do you mean? These all refer to things that have not happened yet. Nothing already happened. Did you think told represented a real past event that actually happened already not an imaginary possibility yet to be realized? It’s just like what happens in It would be better if somebody told him the truth.  That’s not a real past; it means the same thing as It would be better if someone were to tell him the truth.

I think you already gave a valid answer in your question! I mean we should think along these lines, such as "would be better", to capture the implicature of the statement. Perhaps we should replace the unreal past verb with another that gives almost the same meaning of 'it's high time' expression. The unreal past can mean hypothetical situations, like the one you just used, but it can also mean different things, like the statement in my question.

What do you mean it's something different in the statement in your question? Both It’s time he do something and It’s time he did something alike represent unreal, "not yet done" situations; the difference is that the second is more remote a possibility than the first because backshifting is one way to add remoteness; it's also more traditional.

I think the following subjunctive statements imply different meanings, don't they? 1. It's high time you went to bed. It's past midnight already! 2. I wish I were richer to afford this supercar. 3. I demand he leave immediately.

'It’s high time (that) he were told the truth by somebody.' sounds like it violates Orwell's Sixth to my ears.

@EdwinAshworth Shakespeare in Comedy of Errors, Act IV, scene ii: “ ’Tis time that I were gone. It was two ere I left him, and now the clock strikes one.”

See also 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, and more besides.

@FerasMuhaidat I don't know how to answer your question about whether those "imply different meanings". They're all unreal scenarios, since that have not happened. The mandative one is a little different from the other two, though.

The connotations are slightly different though. The first one alludes to the urgency or necessity of a future action that should have been done earlier. The second one highlights the impossibility or the the unlikelihood of a present situation; while the third one shows the performative nature of demanding or insisting, you name it.

@EdwinAshworth that's the point. There is no correlation between the verb form and the temporal reference made here. The form is past, but the "telling" is still to happen at some point later on.

I can easily find quite a few words Shakespeare used that would fail Orwell's 'outlandish' test. As BillJ says, the preterite would surely be the normal choice nowadays. // @Feras Muhaidat You are assuming that 'was', as a past tense form, must relate to a scenario in the past. But see BillJ's comment; 'was' can be used in  other situations. For instance, 'If he was half a man, he'd stand up to the boss.' Compare using the present simple for a planned future event: 'I fly to Jamaica tomorrow.'

@EdwinAshworth I know you keep forgetting, but if you look around you, you will, I think, find yourself in England. Et in America ego. Which means that you – you and I, we have different senses of propriety with respect to using irrealis were. You there constantly use was in places that we here never would, perhaps because it got drilled out of us by normative education, if nothing else. It is also a matter of register and formality; I would little lament a few missed opportunities in casual carousing countryside use, but crafted prose yet has places it can falute higher, should it wish.

But it's important to look at individual cases, avoid being overly broad-brush. Google 4-grams for  high time he were; high time he was {Google's US corpus data}.

I thought that the debate over If I were and If I was long over. I always use were when speaking to put off all manner of creeps.

@EdwinAshworth I don't assume that "was or were" in our discussion refers to a past situation as I mentioned this multiple times in my comments. Their significance lies in the fact that they confuse learners most of the time when it comes to interpreting the context either for accurate translation or syntactic transformation. The past form distances the action or the state of being from being possible or likely to happen now or in the future.

@Feras Muhaidat  'I am not sure but [that] we should change the past verb in the dependent clause into [a rephrasing using a present tense]' is a comment of yours that indicates lack of clarity on this point.
